# Can't Send Test Mail even the settings are correct

Tags: joomla-3.x, global-configuration, joomla-mail, server-configuration

With reference to the subject mentioned above.. I've spent a couple days with these issue and can't find any answers anywhere.

- i'm able to change and save the global configuration settings.
- i'm able to send test mail with same configuration to another website.
- i'm runnning joomla 3.6.5 @localhost
- using the SMTP option
- and this is the config

Send mail : Yes 
Disable Mass Mail : No 
From Email : xxx@gmail.com 
From Name : xxx 
Mailer : SMTP 
SMTP Host : smtp.gmail.com 
SMTP Port : 465 
SMTP Security : SSL/TLS 
SMTP Authentication : Yes 
SMTP Username : xxx@gmail.com 
SMTP Password : xxx

Error in back-end : No 
Error in console : Uncaught ReferenceError: sendtestmail_url is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement. (sendtestmail.js:6)

Please help me if u have any ideas.. i'm lost.. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/8673/120 or http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18328/120

Comment: it's not duplicate n totally not the same as u mention.. i can send mails from front-end. the problem is i cannot send TEST MAIL from back-end..

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/8673/120 is also a back-end issue. Expanding your question to explain how it's different might help narrow down a solution. What have you tried? e.g. have you tried the solution at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15591/120

Comment: Ig you open up your browser inspector (F12) and go to the Console, do you get any errors there?

Comment: Try testing SMTP with localhost and see if that goes through:     Mailer: SMTP,    
SMTP Authentication: No,    
SMTP Security: None,    
SMTP Port: 25,    
SMTP Host: localhost

Comment: look at the question again.. tq..

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the Joomla cache may solve your problem.

See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/11098 for details.